Azure KQL log query
I am using below query
Syslog
| where Computer has "testhost"
| where ProcessName == "ServiceStatus"
| where SyslogMessage has "iptables.service: active"
| count

To set up azure alert using cli and I am getting below error
  (BadRequest) Number of evaluation periods must be 1 for queries that do not project the 'TimeGenerated' column of type 'datetime' Activity ID: e7a38f1c-43b2-47c9-9f6a-xxxxx.
  Code: BadRequest
  Message: Number of evaluation periods must be 1 for queries that do not project the 'TimeGenerated' column of type 'datetime' Activity ID: e7a38f1c-43b2-47c9-9f6a-xxxxxx.

if I add below query it works
syslog
| where Computer has "testhost"
| where ProcessName == "ServiceStatus"
| where SyslogMessage has "iptables.service: active"
| summarize count() by TimeGenerated, _ResourceId

If I use working query it does not show results and hence no alert will trigger
   No results found from the last 24 hours  

I want to display count output is 0 to fire alert and how to fix the query?
az cli command for reference
az monitor scheduled-query create --action $your-action-group --name iptables --resource-group your-rg --scope your-scope --description 'Health check for the service iptables is down in host' --condition 'count '\''Placeholder_1'\'' = 0 resource id _ResourceId at least 1 violations out of 5 aggregated points' --condition-query 'Placeholder_1=Syslog
    | where Computer has "testhost"
    | where ProcessName == "ServiceStatus"
    | where SyslogMessage has "iptables.service: active"
    | summarize count() by TimeGenerated, _ResourceId' --evaluation-frequency 1m --severity 1 --window-size 1m



Number of evaluation periods must be 1 for queries that do not project the 'TimeGenerated' column of type 'datetime':

After examining the error, I found that the issue is with the TimeGenereated field in the query. You need to add a condition for TimeGenerated column as shown below to execute the query in a regular time intervals.
Syslog
| where Computer has "testhost"
| where ProcessName == "ServiceStatus"
| where SyslogMessage has "iptables.service: active"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| summarize count() by TimeGenerated, _ResourceId

Alternatively, you can also use extend operator to include the timegenerated condition in your query.
extend TimeGenerated = ago(12h)

After modifying the query, accordingly, try running the below CLI command to create an action group scheduled alerts.
az monitor scheduled-query create --action mynew --name iptables --resource-group xxxx --scope $scope --description 'Health check for the service iptables is down in host' --condition "count 'Placeholder_1' > 360 resource id _ResourceId at least 1 violations out of 5 aggregated points" --condition-query Placeholder_1="Syslog | where Computer has "testhost" | where ProcessName == "ServiceStatus" | where SyslogMessage has "iptables.service: active" | where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) | summarize count() by TimeGenerated, _ResourceId"

Reference: az monitor scheduled-query create
